# measure network performance with NSURLSessionTaskMetrics

Tags: ios, performance, networking, nsurlsession

`NSURLSessionTaskMetrics` was introduced since iOS10, which is very helpful.

But i am still feel confused about the property `transactionMetrics`, which is an array of `NSURLSessionTaskTransactionMetrics`.

I want to know, if there are more than one transaction metrics in the array, how do i measure the performance of the task? simply summate all  their time, or just pick one of them, if so which one to use?

I've got an rough idea that during the task execution, the session may use more than one transaction to accomplish the task.

But can any one give a more detail description about that, the transaction executed in order  or concurrently .

looking forward for anyone could help